# Virtualbox export appliance

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have an Ubuntu OS installed using virtualbox. Inside the Ubuntu OS, I have installed QEMU, GCC for ARM and GDB for communicating between ARM and QEMU. My question is, if I export this image using the "Export Appliance" option from VirtualBox and use it another machine, will that contain the QEMU, GCC for ARM and GDB installation in that image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an appliance includes the disk image(s), so any software installed inside the virtual machine will be part of the appliance.  That's kind of the whole point of exporting an appliance.

Comment: thanks. I was able to see the software packages in my exported appliance.